# Measuring statistical consistency and reliability

Tags: statistics, mathematical-modeling, variance

I am trying to score reliability (or variability) for a machine learning model I'm working on and I cannot quite get my head around it.  As an example, I have some people who perform a task three times per week for 10 weeks.  I have other people who perform the same task, say, 10 times for three weeks during the 10 week period.  And maybe I have people performing the task 30 times in one week and resting over the other nine weeks.

They all average 3 tasks per week, but I need to give them different variabilities.  How would I score that?

Comment: Do you want a measure of how "spread out" they work during the 10 weeks? So for instance performing the task 30 in one week maps to $1$, while performing three tasks per week for 10 weeks maps to $0$ (if these are the extreme cases) and 10 times for three weeks maps to something in between?

Comment: Yes... that sounds right.  I want to understand who performs better if they do it all at once or spread it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Discrete_random_variable):

For your data sets, this would be 
\begin{align}
a&=(3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3) \quad&\mapsto\quad &\rm{std} (a)=0 \\
b&=(10,10,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)  \quad&\mapsto \quad &\rm{std} (b)=4.8305 \dots \\
c&=(30,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)  \quad&\mapsto \quad &\rm{std} (c)=9.4868\dots
\end{align}

Note that it doesn't matter where the $10$s (or the $30$) are placed in the list.

Comment: That looks good.  Thanks!